# How to add column with links in DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm using datatable from here https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html
And I'd like to add one extra column for CRUD operation. And this is how I was trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax": "../User/GetDataTable",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "FIRST_NAME" },
            { "data": "LAST_NAME" },
            { "data": "DESCRIPTION" }
            { defaultContent: '<a href="' + JSON.stringify({data: "FIRST_NAME" }) + '">LINK</a>'
    }
    ],
    "order":
    [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

The problem is that the LINK looks like this: `http://localhost:4259/%7B` or without JSON.stringify: `http://localhost:4259/[object Object]` and i expect LINK eg. `http://localhost:4259/Tom` (`Tom` is value from `FIRST_NAME`)

Comment: use render column from datatable API  docs....https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37794314/jquery-datatable-select-list-within-column/37794635#37794635

Comment: @NitinDhomse, i tried, but always `undefined (undefined)`

Comment: Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```
...
            { "data": "FIRST_NAME" },
            { "data": "LAST_NAME" },
            { "data": "DESCRIPTION" }
            {   
               data: 'FIRST_NAME',
               "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a href="' + data + '">Edit</a>';
            }
    }
...
```